# How can I bind one element to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I didn't know how to properly describe my issue in the title, sorry if the problem is slightly different from the titled one:

For jsp/style related issues, for each div (Polymer's paper-button), I have to create a hidden checkbox.

```
<%int i; %>
<form ACTION="Computation.jsp">
        <% for(i=0; i<n; i++) {%> 
            <input type="checkbox" id="ch<%=i %>" name="cid">
            <div class="paperbutton" id="pb<%=i %>">Test</div>

        <% } %>
        <input type="submit" id="sub">
</form>
```

What my script would have to do is to check the checkbox when the related button in pressed:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {          
                   $('#pb.<%=i%>').on('click', function() {
                    if($('#ch<%=i%>').is(':checked')) {
                       $('#ch<%=i%>').prop('checked', false);
                       }
                    else { $('#ch<%=i%>').prop('checked', true);};
                   });
            });
</script>
```

But obviously I can not mix java and jQuery this way. How can I perform the same action using jQuery only?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use various traversal methods to find the related DOM elements. For simplicity I have wrapped `DIV` and `checkbox` in a container div.

*HTML*

```
<% for(i=0; i<n; i++) {%> 
    <div class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cid">
        <div class="paperbutton" >Test</div>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    //Bind event using the class provided to div       
    $('.paperbutton').on('click', function() {
        var checkbox = $(this).closest('.container').find(':checkbox');
        //var checkbox = $(this).prev(':checkbox');
        checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

References:

- [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)